# Why do we use señorito over señorcito, but amorcito over amorito?

Tags: diminutivos

I was just speaking with my Peruvian girlfriend, who told me that no one ever uses *señorcito* but rather *señorito*. But we use *amorcito* instead of *amorito*.

Both words end with a stressed *-or* and have two syllables. Yet the diminutive form of each has a different suffix. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: We would never use "amorito" in Spanish, but in regard to your GF's statement, I don't know if I fully agree. I could use "señorcito" for a tiny guy, but ["Señorito"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=Yw4KagvmtDXX2fDr4V3m) means "Hijo de un señor o de persona de representación/joven acomodado" so it's not just a matter of using the suffix right. Both words can have different meanings.

Answer (score 8):

Why we say `amorcito` instead of `amorito` when we say for example "cas**ita**" as diminutive for `casa`?

> La formación de diminutivos con el **sufijo -ita** se hace añadiendo dicha terminación a la base de la palabra, como en el caso de casa, cuya base es cas- y se forma casita.
>
> **El sufijo -cita (así como -ecita) es una variación de -ita, cuyo uso se debe más a la preferencia de los hablantes que a normas gramaticales establecidas**, y normalmente forma los diminutivos a partir de la palabra entera y no solo de la base: a la palabra `clase` se le añade el sufijo -cita, y forma `clasecita`, pero no "*clascita*".
>
> También hay palabras que, en función de la variedad dialectal que se hable, pueden tomar diferentes formas del diminutivo, como en el caso de `mano`, que puede decirse manito, manita, manecita.
>
> [Source: Fundeu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/diminutivos-2951/)

The difference between *señorito* and *señor**cito*** can be tricky. It could seem that both *Señor**ito*** and *Señor**cito*** are diminutives of `señor` (like a small *señor*). That is true to some extent, but the thing is that the word ["señorito"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=Yw4KagvmtDXX2fDr4V3m) conveys that is not small not in size (even when they already are so) but the *little lord*.

["Señorito"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=Yw4KagvmtDXX2fDr4V3m) means

> Hijo de un señor o de persona de representación.

Check some of the other meanings on the dictionary:

> Amo, con respecto a los criado
>
> Joven acomodado y ocioso.

So, in *señor**cito*** the diminutive conveys "small" in size, but in *señorito* the word carries the meaning of "the small kid/son of the lord" (*el hijo del señor*).

Comment: Efectivamente, los diminutivos se forman un poco como los gentilicios — mediamente por medio de alguna u otra regla fonética pero con un buen toque de azar. También, hay que recordar los otros diminutivos como *-ín*, *-iño*, *-illo*, *-ingo*, *-ico*, todos de los cuales admiten los infijos *-e-* y *-ec-* (además de poderse combinar)

Comment: Digo, ***-c-*** y *-ce* como infijos

Comment: @Diego creo que tu respuesta es satisfactoria y suficiente. Sin embargo, no puedo dejar de recomendar un artículo que baraja otra posibilidad distinta para este caso concreto: _en el par señor/señora la formación del diminutivo se hace sobre el modelo del femenino_ — http://www.academia.edu/5888100/_Morfofonolog%C3%ADa_de_la_formación_de_diminutivos_en_español_reglas_morfológicas_o_restricciones_fonológicas_en_A._Fábregas_et_alii_eds._Los_l%C3%ADmites_de_la_Morfolog%C3%ADa._Estudios_ofrecidos_a_Soledad_Varela_Ortega_Madrid_UAM_2012_págs._55-78_en_colaboración_con_Théophile_Ambadiang_

Comment: @guillem, esa de hecho podría ser otra respuesta válida y muy interesante para esta pregunta.

Comment: Lo sé @diego, el artículo no tiene desperdicio, pero al no encontrar ningún momento de más de 5 minutos para escribir tranquilo, me ha podido la pereza :(