# Ortografía de i al final de la palabra: ¿mami o mamy?

Tags: ortografía

Tengo esta duda ortográfica y no he encontrado una buena fuente que la aclare.

La palabra *mami* (¿o *mamy*?) no existe en el diccionario español, pero debería poder escribirla correctamente. Yo prefiero la ye final, basándome en una regla que yo mismo me inventé (a veces hacemos eso y vivimos convencidos): si es tónica, es **i** (vendí, corrí, maní, así, iraquí, alelí); y si es átona, es **y** (Uruguay, rey, soy, hay).

Buscando ejemplos encontré la palabra *taxi*, que anula mi teoría. Pero también en la RAE está *sexy*, lo que me hace dudar.

Hay una regla que dice que llevan **y** las palabras terminadas en diptongo *ay, ey, oy, uy*. Pero nada me dice que *no* pueda usar una **y** final en otros casos, considerando además que si la palabra siguiente comienza con vocal, la [i] se va a comportar como semivocal igual que en un diptongo.

La crítica que se me hace al escribir *mamy* es que se trata de un anglicismo. De acuerdo, la mayoría de las palabras que pienso sin diptongo final son de origen inglés (*tony, sexy, hobby*)... pero *mamy* no es un anglicismo.

Comment: He borrado mi respuesta, porque te estaba respondiendo con la misma norma del diptongo que ya conoces.

Comment: Nótese que [guirigay](http://dle.rae.es/?w=guirigay&m=form&o=h) termina en Y tónica. Por cierto, muy bueno lo de _a veces hacemos eso y vivimos convencidos_ : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo coincido en que siempre lo he escrito como `mami` o `papi` y las variantes terminadas en -y me parecen un anglicismo. He podido encontrar esto en el DRAE sobre ["papá"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=km1nGgx0bD6IFPUmdv) y ["mamá"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=mam%E1)

> En todo el ámbito hispánico se usa también la forma hipocorística **papi**.
>
> En todo el ámbito hispánico se usa también la forma hipocorística **mami**.

Y por supuesto tuve que buscar en el diccionario ["hipocorístico, ca."](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=hipocor%EDstica), que es una "forma diminutiva, abreviada o infantil, [que] se usa como designación cariñosa, familiar", y como tal, quizá las reglas de formación de este diminutivo se [salgan un poco de la norma](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14895/5481) (nótese que los enlaces recogen las formas "papacito/mamacita", "papaíto/mamaíta" y "papito/mamita", que sí siguen las reglas de formación de diminutivos).

Answer (score 1):

La lógica mía, mucho más elemental que la de Rodrigo, porque estoy muy poco ilustrado de verdad en temas de lengua; me aconseja escribir "mami" y "papi" porque mamá  y papá se escriben con vocales simples y de tal forma habrá de escribirse su forma diminutiva cariñosa; con una vocal simple.

Es de notar que en francés "mamie" significa cariñosamente abuela y no mamá. Pero abuelo, cariñosamente, es "papy"; debido, creo yo, a que es una forma masculina y a que hay muy pocas terminaciones, en francés, en "i". La comparación del español con el francés se debe a la latinidad cómplice e interrelacionada de ambas lenguas.

Comment: He de añadir que "mamie" se pronuncia mami, en francés. No se dice la "e". En realidad hay muchas plabras francesas que terminan en "i" : "souci", "taxi", "ennui", "merci", ....

Answer (score 0):

- La respuesta es simple; **mami**, es el diminutivo de *mamá*, ya que siempre los diminutivos en el español terminan con la letra "**i**" y no "**y**" *(ye)*.

---

- Con respecto a: **Uruguay**, **Paraguay**, **Rey**, son palabras que están echas en español antiguo, donde la letra "**y**", era utilizada como lo es utilizada hoy la letra "**i**".

---

- La palabra *sexy*, es un anglicismo, (derivado del ingles), es uno de esos casos que permanece la palabra tal cual como se escribe en su idioma de origen.